# Instalar WindowBuilder en Eclipse - Java

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, windowbuilder

Buenas noches programadores. Para instalar WindowBuilder en Eclipse (IDE) para Java, alguien lo a instalado recientemente? No he podido segun la documentacion oficial en https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Alguna ayuda? Es recomendable o el de netbeans funciona mejor para Clase Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El WindowBuilder para Eclipse es excelente. Te ayudara mucho. Mientras vas diseñando, el codigo se escribe. Para instalarlo deber ir a HELP--Install new software.
Es recomendable tener versiones de Eclipse y WindowBuilder actualizadas y Java 1.8.